# Dockerfile: check if build machine is Windows

Tags: docker, dockerfile, line-endings, docker-for-windows

We have a Docker project that is shared by developers using Windows, Mac or Linux.

Unfortunately we can't [control the way the project is cloned](https://help.github.com/articles/dealing-with-line-endings/), so Windows developers might end up with bad line-endings when building the Docker image and the build could fail because of that.

To fix this issue, we added a line to our Dockerfile to replace all Windows line endings with Unix line endings before the build process is started:

```
ADD . /app
RUN find . -type f -exec sed -i 's/\x0d//g' {} \+
```

But the problem is, the build is now much slower, even on Linux and Mac boxes.

I would like to `RUN` this command only if the build is happening on a Windows machine. But is there a way for the Dockerfile to detect that?

Answer (score 0):

Can you try to replace the the "ADD ..." line by something like this:

```
RUN git clone <your.repo.git> src
ADD src /app
```

I have not tested but the files will be created by the git of your Dockerfile base image, so everyone should have the same files.